# Prove $M$ is not free

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, free-modules

I'm doing an exercise with
$$A = \mathbb{R}[x, y, z] / \langle x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1 \rangle \; .$$

We have
$$N = \{ (xf, yf, zf) \}, M = \{ (f, g, h) \mid xf + yg + zh = 0 \}$$
as submodules of $A^3$. First I was asked to prove $N \cong A$ and $M \oplus N \cong A^3$. Both follow by considering the "dot product" by (x, y ,z) map, that is $(f, g, h) \to xf + yg +zh$, whose kernel is precisely $M$ and whose restriction to $N$ yields the first isomorphism. We thus construct an exact sequence with $M, A^3, A$ and this map, and since $A$ is free over itself the sequence splits, hence the second isomorphism (since $A \cong N$). I'm them asked to prove $M$ is not free. This is where I'm stuck. I don't know if I'm missing something obvious but I have no clue how to do this. Maybe any two elements are linearly dependent? Or is there some other useful property of free modules that I'm missing? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If $M$ is free, then $M\oplus A\cong A^3$ tells you that $M$ would have to be isomorphic to $A^2$. Maybe you can show that $M$ cannot be generated by two elements; I have a feeling that you need at least three generators.

Comment: There are many proofs, none of them quite easy. One of the earliest proofs come from what is usually called 'hairy ball theorem' from geometry. $M$ is closely related to the tangent bundle of the real sphere.

Comment: @Mohan I might have misinterpreted the author's statement. This exercise is the "algebraic version" of the previous, which I skipped since I had no knowledge of vector bundles. Thanks to your comment I reread both statements, and noticed that in the previous it asks to prove the associated module $M$ (of the tangent bundle) is not free, while in the current we have "Prove [...] and that $M \oplus N \cong A^3$ **;** still $M$ is not free". Thanks for the help, I probably misunderstood what the exercise asked, the "still M is not free" is likely stated as the conclusion of the previous exercise.